# Arduino based digital to AC conversion schematic

Tags: arduino, timer, dac

I am trying to build an Arduino based system for sending electric pulses, of 24V, 40mA sinusoidal. Each pulse is in a burst of 5000 microsecond, and each pulse is about 20 - 800 microsecond. These pulses are grouped in a burst - which there are 10-15 in a second. So the logic that the Arduino could follow is as follows:

1. Send a 20 - 800 microsecond pulse of 24V, 40mA in a burst.
2. A burst is of duration 0.4 - 0.6 seconds.

The Arduino could easily help in this logic, and so the choice to prototype. Now, to achieve the logic above I plan to use a NE555 timer in the following schematic (see attached diagram).

To achieve the power requirements I am adding a 24V battery to a MAX533 (could use another digital to Analog chip too! - any suggestions welcome). To convert digital to analog, via the Arduino(send the sinus wave digital parameters via the Arduino to the MAX533-type DAC, and get a pulse + burst.

Is this the correct approach to the problem? Also, what Digital to Analog converter chips can give 24V, 40mA sinusoidal signals. In the diagram I have used MAX533 but that is for illustrative purposes. The MOSFET arrangement coupled with the NE555 allows the bursts to be formed.

Again, the schema I may have generated may be incorrect, any help + reference is appreciated, thanks in anticipation. 
[image: ArduinoSchema]

Comment: (1) 24 V peak, peak to peak or RMS? (2) Why would you use a 555 when you have a microcontroller at your disposal? (3) DAC with 24 V output is unlikely. (4) Do you care where in the HF cycle the output is switched off?

Comment: Points (1) 24V peak to peak (2) Correct I needed to validate this, (3) Right on this, too, so there is no way I can send data (to a DAC) via the Arduino to get 24V at desired pulse rate, and burst rate?

Comment: Point (4) how does it matter in the HF cycle whether the out is off? Thanks

Comment: (1 + 3) You may even have trouble finding a DAC with negative output. (4) Switching the HF at zero-cross will minimise harmonics and EM radiation. (5) If your load doesn't need to be grounded you might be able to use a H-bridge or a Class-D amplifier to drive the load. This will get around the half-supply DC bias your are probably going to have from your DAC.

Comment: The load is a sensor, that needs 24VAC bursts of upto 40mA, and it may not be grounded. Oh, class D op amp based Digital to AC conversion? A class D op amp is the way to go with an LC circuit?

Comment: Output is not AC, it is PWM.

Comment: @codebeat I need a sinusoidal wave output PWM is good?

Answer (score 1):

It will help to explain what you want to drive with it because maybe it is not required the way you want it, maybe you don't need it. The 555-timer is also vague because you are using a MCU that can provide a pulse on interrupt, it could be possible your way of thinking isn't correct to achieve a solution. A (perfect) sinus output is impossible with such simple setup, it is on/off switching at a frequency, so it will output a harsh square wave when you also implement the negative side of the wave.

Anyway, take a look at this video, it will explain how inverters (I think that is what you want) work and what you need to implement it correctly:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVeERT4nyz8

However, because we still don't know what the exact purpose is of your idea, this is just a suggestion.